# Good source for learning about Binary Classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification

When dealing with binary classification, I most often find myself estimating a logistic regression model. I have tried a few other approaches as well, but to be honest I feel like I know way too little about all of the other possibilities.

I understand that it isn't as easy as following a 'model choice' guide. So what I'm looking for is a source where I can read up on the theory behind the different approaches, and then take it from there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf) also covers linear and quadratic discriminant analysis, tree-based methods (classification trees, random forests, bagging, and boosing), and support vector machines at a reasonably introductory level. [The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) goes into more depth, and adds in neural networks.